# how to configure ISCSI fault tolerance in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, iscsi, fault-tolerance, open-iscsi

how to configure ISCSI fault tolerance in ubuntu 12.04 Anyone has a tutorial or steps to?! thanks in advance knowing that initiator and server are ubuntu

Comment: Have you researched and attempted to configure it?

Comment: The site is a community site to help eachother. Better detailed questions get more than one excellent suggestion and answers. Do post what problems you ran into and where you need help with.

Answer (score 3):

I had Ubuntu 10.10 working with my Equallogic PS6000 very well. I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 and it stopped working. I am not new to open-iscsi/multipath tools - but it is being a real bugger. Anyway, maybe some of this will help, the vagaries of chap are not included and I promise that it is likely incomplete but this should point you in the right direction:

Install `open-iscsi`
Set up your interfaces:

```
$iscsiadm --mode iface --op=new --interface iscsi-1
$iscsiadm --mode iface --op=new --interface iscsi-2

$iscsiadm --mode iface --op=update --interface iscsi-1 --name=iface.net_ifacename --value=eth1 

$iscsiadm --mode iface --op=update --interface iscsi-2 --name=iface.net_ifacename --value=eth2
```

Discover luns:

```
$iscsiadm -m discovery -t sendtargets -p 10.0.1.10
```

You should see a list of permitted luns, they should look something like:

```
10.0.1.10:3260,1 iqn.2001-05.com.equallogic:xxxxxxxx
10.0.1.10:3260,1 iqn.2001-05.com.equallogic:xxxxxxxx
```

log in to the luns:

```
$iscsiadm --mode node --targetname iqn.2001-05.com.equallogic:xxxxxxxx --portal 10.0.1.10:3260 --login all
```

Verify you are connected:

```
$iscsiadm -m session
tcp: [1] 10.0.1.10:3260,1 iqn.2001-05.com.equallogic:xxxxxxxx
tcp: [2] 10.0.1.10:3260,1 iqn.2001-05.com.equallogic:xxxxxxxx
```

Tell it to log in automatically at startup:

```
$iscsiadm --mode node --targetname iqn.2001-05.com.equallogic:xxxxxxxx --portal 10.0.1.10:3260 --op update -n node.startup -v automatic
```

Install `multipath-tools`

Create `/etc/multipath.conf` - here is a sample:

```
##################################
defaults {
    user_friendly_names yes
    find_multipaths yes
}
#ignore local drives
blacklist {
    devnode "^sd[a,b]$"
}
#Pay attention to these devices
blacklist_exceptions {
    devnode "^dm-0"
    devnode "^dm-1"
    devnode "^dm-2"
    devnode "^sd[c,d,e,f]"
}
#device description for a PS6000
devices {
    device {
      vendor                  "EQLOGIC"
      product                 "100E-00"
      path_grouping_policy    multibus
      getuid_callout          "/lib/udev/scsi_id --whitelisted --device=/dev/%n"
      features                "0 queue_if_no_path"
      path_checker            readsector0
      path_selector           "round-robin 0"
      failback                immediate
      rr_min_io               10
      rr_weight               priorities
    }
}
#############################
```

Restart multipath tools -

Check topology/map:

```
multipath -ll
```

(here is where Ubuntu 12.04 broke - I stopped seeing anything)

expected result:

```
    myLun (UUIDxxxxxx) dm-1 EQLOGIC,100E-00
        size=100G features='1 queue_if_no_path' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
        `-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=2 status=active
        |- 4:0:0:0 sde 8:64 active ready running
        `- 3:0:0:0 sdc 8:32 active ready running
```

I hope this helps. Now off to fix mine...  :-)

Comment: Thanks very much... Also i have the same problem so if you have solve it please inform me...Thanks in advance

Comment: It turns out that the `features                "0 queue_if_no_path"` part of the equallogic multipath.conf entry was causing the problem. As best I can tell it impacts the functioning of /lib/udev/rules.d/95-kpartx.rules when it is called. commenting out the above multipath.conf entry fixed it.. Sorry I can't say more specifics - off to fight other fires...